# Simple Program Does Not Work Correctly

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Welcome
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a = input.nextDouble();
        double b = input.nextDouble();
        double c = input.nextDouble();

        double rezultat = - b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c) / 2 * a;

        System.out.println(rezultat);
    }
}
```

I wonder why this code does not work as it should.

Printed result is always: NaN

Comment: Just a note: `{expression}/2` is called before `2*a`

Comment: Without knowing what your input is, the question is unanswerable. If the string "nan" is in your input, obviously the output will be NaN.

Comment: What are the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` when this happens?  When you debug this, which operations in that calculation isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: Odds are `Math.sqrt()` is taking in a negative number. From the api : "If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN."  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)

Answer (score 1):

`Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)`

This is the portion that will return NaN. If you plug in the values of (1, 0, 1) which is x^2 + 1, you will get NaN as it never crosses the x line.

In other words, if Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c) < 0, you should EXPECT NaN.

If you were trying to do the quadratic formula, then the proper equation would be:

```
double rezultat = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
```

You need to take into account order of operations, even more so in Java. Your original operation would have returned something that would not have been x.

Additionally, there are TWO expected results for +/- quadratic.

```
double rezultat2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
```

The rough program output should be:

```
    double bsqm4ac = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c);
    if (bsqm4ac < 0.0) {// no intersections of x axis i.e. x^2+2
        System.out.println("No value found");
    } else if (bsqm4ac == 0.0) { //one intersection of x axis i.e. x^2
        System.out.println(-b / (2 * a) + 0.0); // we can get a -0.0 here if
                                                // b = 0, because doubles
    } else { //two intersections of x axis ie. x^2 - 1
        System.out.println((-b - bsqm4ac) / (2 * a) + "," + (-b + bsqm4ac)
                / (2 * a));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[The `Math.sqrt` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) returns NaN (not-a-number) if its argument is negative. Once you have a NaN, basically any other operation on it will just produce NaN.

Note that not all quadratic functions have real roots; if you want a result other than NaN, you need to ensure that *b*<sup>2</sup> ≥ 4*ac*.

Also:

- As kingdamian42 points out in a comment above, you need `/ (2 * a)` rather than `/ 2 * a`. (The latter means "divide by two, then multiply by *a*".)
- I think it's better to write `b * b` rather than `Math.pow(b, 2)`. The latter is slower and typically has greater roundoff error. (I'd mainly consider `Math.pow` to be useful for non-trivial powers.)